# about CONFIG_NO_HZ in kernel

Tags: linux, schedule

So if CONFIG_NO_HZ is set, I believe it will make a tickless kernel. But I believe this just means when the system is idle, it might become tickless in order to save energy. When it's working, it is still tick kernel, right? Thanks:>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, yes.

There are ongoing projects to make the periodic tick go away also when not idle, but that's a lot of work with many changes, and it's unclear whether it will ever be completed.